# PHP sem resposta no comando fetch

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis, conexão

estou estudando com um livro use a cabeça e o seguinte praticamente copiei e colei o código de exemplo apenas mudando os nomes das variáveis e não estou tendo o retorno com o meu código, na verdade o que aparece no meu resultado final é email sent to: 3x isso porque tenho 3 cadastros no meu banco de dados, mas os valores não estão sendo colocadas dentro das variáveis logo, a função não esta funcionando direito, não esta mandando email nem retorno email sent to: exemplo@teste.com Desde já agradeço.

```
<?php
  $de = 'my@email.com';
  $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
  $texto = $_POST['elvismail'];

  /*creating connection*/
  $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'ELVIS_STORE')
  or die ('Erro ao conectar o banco');  

  /*command SQL*/
  $query = "SELECT * FROM LISTA_EMAIL"; 

  /*getting result*/
  $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die ('erro na segunda etapa');   

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
   $para = $row['email'];
   $nome = $row['nome'];
   $sobrenome = $row['nome'];
   mail($para, $assunto, $texto, 'De: ' . $de);
   echo 'Email sent to: ' . $para . '<br />';
 }
  mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: nome de tabela está em ***MAIÚSCULO***?
Segundo: As conexões estão corretas?
Terceiro: As constantes mudanças do PHP em relação ao MySQL (depreciação do mysql_* em relação ao mysqli_*) me fez pesquisa e te orientar a trocar, após o SELECT, o trecho de código assim:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

/* execute statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name, $code);

/* fetch values */
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
}

/* close statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Willian, sobre a questão do banco estar em maiúsculo sim está e isso não foi um problema pq antes de retirar os dados do banco criei um formulário para que enviassem os mesmos e deu tudo certo (mesmo usando em maiúsculo). sobre as conexões usei o mesmo procedimento do formulário anterior para usar conexão ou seja da mesma forma que criei a conexão para o envio usei para a retira e a conexão esta ok (tanto que o browser me entrega a mensagem "email sent to:" 3x o detalhe é que após o to: deveria aparecer o email das pessoas cadastradas, que por sinal são 3 e não aparece.

Comment: sobre a depreciação eu não entendi vc recomenda que eu continue usando mysqli ou mude para mysql (_fetch) e sobre o teu código... daí ficou muito difícil pra eu entender estou no inicio e o que esta acontecendo parece básico, mas realmente não descobri ainda o que se trata e o livro mostra somente isso. Obrigado por tudo de qualquer forma.

Comment: Os livros estão desatualizados, principalmente essa série "Use a Cabeça". Esse trecho de código eu peguei da própria documentação do php. Recomendo você acessar: (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).
Sobre a questão de não aparecer, dê um `print_r($teuArray)` antes do While para verificar qual seu formato.

Comment: Oi William este é o resultado do print_r($meuarray) mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 3 [type] => 0 )

Comment: Isso é o `print_r($result)`?? Parece `print_r(mysqli_query)`. Não veio os dados do banco, só informações.

Comment: Exato e é aqui que mora o que não estou entendendo pq criei variável result dize que ele é igual a mysqli_query($conexao, $query) caso contrario me mostre a msg de erro (pelo menos foi o que entendi da parte do código $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die ('erro na segunda etapa'); e quando dei o print_r ($result) são estes dados que ela me traz acho que se ela trouxesse os dados de dentro do banco mesmo o problema seria sanado.

Comment: Mas o result vai trazer isso mesmo, o que você tem que colocar é o $row.
`print_r($row)`. Isso antes do while. dê um exit() após.

Comment: William obrigado pela sua atenção já resolvi aqui, na verdade estava tudo certo a função a fórmula ali em cima está tudo ok o detalhe é que dentro do array While a variável $row ['email']; deveria estar escrita $row['EMAIL'] pois foi assim que escrevi no banco de dados, fiz essa alteração para os demais e deu tudo certo. Obrgado movemente